# EventTrigger RoutedEvent amimation in wpf xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers, routed-events

I want an animation to be launched when `MyObject.IsGlowing = true` so I did this (I'm in a `<DataTemplate>` if that can help)

```
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Name="MyEllipse">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <RadialGradientBrush >
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="red" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="red"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush >
    </Ellipse.Fill>
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source=IsGlowing}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryBoard">
                    <Storyboard Name="MyStoryBoard" >
                        //Animation
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

but I got this error *"Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger"* so I changed it to

```
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Name="MyEllipse">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <RadialGradientBrush >
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="red" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="red"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush >
    </Ellipse.Fill>
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="?">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryBoard">
                    <Storyboard Name="MyStoryBoard" >
                        //Animation
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

But i have no idea what to put in RoutedEvent...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed DataTriggers to be directly used/specified within an elements Triggers collection. However, you can use a Style to apply one.

- http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Help_Why_cant_I_use_DataTriggers_with_controls_in_WPF.aspx